# How to find number of unique values per a key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as,

```
{'drink': ["'57 Chevy with a White License Plate",
  "'57 Chevy with a White License Plate",
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '110 in the shade',
  '110 in the shade',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '155 Belmont',
  '155 Belmont',
  '155 Belmont',
  '155 Belmont',
  '24k nightmare',
  '24k nightmare',
  '24k nightmare',
  '24k nightmare',
  '252',
  '252'],
 'ingredient': ['Creme de Cacao',
  'Vodka',
  'Absolut Kurant',
  'Grand Marnier',
  'Grand Marnier',
  'Midori melon liqueur',
  'Malibu rum',
  'Amaretto',
  'Cranberry juice',
  'Pineapple juice',
  'Lager',
  'Tequila',
  'Malibu rum',
  'Light rum',
  '151 proof rum',
  'Dark Creme de Cacao',
  'Cointreau',
  'Milk',
  'Coconut liqueur',
  'Vanilla ice-cream',
  'Dark rum',
  'Light rum',
  'Vodka',
  'Orange juice',
  'Goldschlager',
  'Jägermeister',
  'Rumple Minze',
  '151 proof rum',
  '151 proof rum',
  'Wild Turkey']}
```

I would like to find the number of unique ingredients per a drink as

1. Drink **57 Chevy with a White License Plate** has 2 unique ingredients,
2. Drink **1-900-FUK-MEUP** has 7 unique ingredients('Absolut Kurant',
   'Grand Marnier',
   'Grand Marnier',
   'Midori melon liqueur',
   'Malibu rum',
   'Amaretto',
   'Cranberry juice',
   'Pineapple juice')

```
out_dict = {'drink':['57 Chevy with a White License Plate','1-900-FUK-MEUP'],'unique_count':[2,7]}
```

Could you please write your suggestions/answers how to get it done?

Comment: Is your structure a kind of mapping ? This is totally not the approriate structure to do so

Comment: Why have you stored your data in this structure? It's bizarre; did you make that dictionary?

Comment: @azro are you referring to this dict output structure: out_dict ?

Comment: Not really, Look both answers, both have built the good dict, `{drinkKey:ingredientList}`

Comment: @roganjosh Yes, I have converted a datatable to a form of dictionary, what's the error in it please let me know.

Comment: @roganjosh yes its a pydata table frame - for more info  you can go through https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame.html?highlight=to_dict#datatable.Frame.to_dict

Comment: Ah ok, then ignore my last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your structure is innapropriate, let's build a better one as a `dict` with mappings

```
{drinkKey:ingredientList}
```

- make pairs between your two list `('drink', 'ingredient')`
- group these on the first item, the drink, to get `{drink:[('drink', 'ingredient'), ('drink', 'ingredient')]`
- keep ingredient only in the list

```
pairs = list(zip(data['drink'], data['ingredient']))
ingr_per_drink = {k : list(map(itemgetter(1), v)) 
                  for k,v in groupby(sorted(pairs, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}
for drink, ingredients in ingr_per_drink.items():
    # whatever you want
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = {'drink': ["'57 Chevy with a White License Plate",
  "'57 Chevy with a White License Plate",
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '110 in the shade',
  '110 in the shade',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '155 Belmont',
  '155 Belmont',
  '155 Belmont',
  '155 Belmont',
  '24k nightmare',
  '24k nightmare',
  '24k nightmare',
  '24k nightmare',
  '252',
  '252'],
 'ingredient': ['Creme de Cacao',
  'Vodka',
  'Absolut Kurant',
  'Grand Marnier',
  'Grand Marnier',
  'Midori melon liqueur',
  'Malibu rum',
  'Amaretto',
  'Cranberry juice',
  'Pineapple juice',
  'Lager',
  'Tequila',
  'Malibu rum',
  'Light rum',
  '151 proof rum',
  'Dark Creme de Cacao',
  'Cointreau',
  'Milk',
  'Coconut liqueur',
  'Vanilla ice-cream',
  'Dark rum',
  'Light rum',
  'Vodka',
  'Orange juice',
  'Goldschlager',
  'Jägermeister',
  'Rumple Minze',
  '151 proof rum',
  '151 proof rum',
  'Wild Turkey']}

result = defaultdict(set)
for drink, ingredient in zip(data['drink'], data['ingredient']):
    result[drink].add(ingredient)

for drink, unique_ingredient in result.items():
    print("{} has {} unique ingredients: {}".format(drink, len(unique_ingredient), list(unique_ingredient)))
```

Output:

```
'57 Chevy with a White License Plate has 2 unique ingredients: ['Creme de Cacao', 'Vodka']
1-900-FUK-MEUP has 7 unique ingredients: ['Malibu rum', 'Grand Marnier', 'Cranberry juice', 'Pineapple juice', 'Amaretto', 'Midori melon liqueur', 'Absolut Kurant']
110 in the shade has 2 unique ingredients: ['Lager', 'Tequila']
151 Florida Bushwacker has 8 unique ingredients: ['Milk', 'Malibu rum', 'Vanilla ice-cream', 'Light rum', 'Coconut liqueur', 'Dark Creme de Cacao', 'Cointreau', '151 proof rum']
155 Belmont has 4 unique ingredients: ['Light rum', 'Orange juice', 'Dark rum', 'Vodka']
24k nightmare has 4 unique ingredients: ['Jägermeister', '151 proof rum', 'Rumple Minze', 'Goldschlager']
252 has 2 unique ingredients: ['Wild Turkey', '151 proof rum']
```

Comment: Don't say 'try this', please when giving an answer explain what the problem is and what solution you propose and how this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inputs, here i have finalized it and it met with my requirement.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

pairs = list(zip(ex_dict['drink'], ex_dict['ingredient']))

ingr_per_drink = {k : list(map(itemgetter(1), v)) 
                  for k,v in groupby(sorted(pairs, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}

drink_counts = {drink:len(set(ingr)) for drink,ingr in ingr_per_drink.items()}

drink_group_sum = {'drink':[],'unique_ingr':[]}

for k, v in drink_counts.items():
    drink_group_sum['drink'].append(k)
    drink_group_sum['unique_ingr'].append(v)
```

**drink_group_sum** can be viewed as,

```
{'drink': ["'57 Chevy with a White License Plate",
  '1-900-FUK-MEUP',
  '110 in the shade',
  '151 Florida Bushwacker',
  '155 Belmont',
  '24k nightmare',
  '252'],
 'unique_ingr': [2, 7, 2, 8, 4, 4, 2]}
```

Now i can easily pass this dict back to datatable Frame constructor so that it will create a new datatable and can be viewed as,

```
Out[4]: 
   | drink                                 unique_ingr
-- + ------------------------------------  -----------
 0 | '57 Chevy with a White License Plate            2
 1 | 1-900-FUK-MEUP                                  7
 2 | 110 in the shade                                2
 3 | 151 Florida Bushwacker                          8
 4 | 155 Belmont                                     4
 5 | 24k nightmare                                   4
 6 | 252                                             2

[7 rows x 2 columns]
```